# How to view a list of selected item from 'media_picker_builder' in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have copied some code from pub dev for displaying media (images and videos). The codes working fine but I want to see the item that I have selected, can anyone please help me with this?
the code is from the below link here

https://pub.dev/packages/media_picker_builder/example

I want to know to how modify the line "print(selectedFiles)"

thank you

Comment: add a state variable and instead of print do `setState` and then use that variable inside a `ListView.builder`.

Comment: how to use that variable? because am getting an error says "type 'MediaFile' is not a subtype of type 'widget'

Answer (score 0):

First, define the variable that holds your selected files. Eg. `mySelectedFiles`.

Then make use of `setState()` function below `print(selectedFiles)` line. to assign the value to your variable.

You can use that variable further in listview or any imageviewer etc.

**Solution**:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  var mySelectedFiles;

  //Other code.....

  _buildPicker() {
    showModalBottomSheet<Set<MediaFile>>(
      context: navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return PickerWidget(
          withImages: true,
          withVideos: true,
          onDone: (Set<MediaFile> selectedFiles) {
            print(selectedFiles);
            setState(() { 
                mySelectedFiles = selectedFiles;    //<= see here
            });
            Navigator.pop(context);      
          },
          onCancel: () {
            print("Cancelled");
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  //Other code.....
  //use mySelectedFiles variable further

 }
```

Comment: thank you but am getting this error " 'MediaFile' is not a subtype of type 'widget' ".      am using a listview.builder

Comment: how to use that "mySelectedFiles" variable? because am getting an error says "type 'MediaFile' is not a subtype of type 'widget'